# Можно ли запланировать выключение ПК Windows используя только телефон?

Tags: android, windows-10, remote

У меня есть роутер, к нему подключены мой компьютер и мой телефон. Могу ли я запланировать удалённо выключение своего компьютера через свой телефон, но при этом не скачивать никаких серверов на компьютер? Ищу в Гугле этот же вопрос, но постоянно говорит что нужно установить какие-либо сервера на ПК, потом это же приложение на телефон. Мой ПК — Windows 10, телефон — Android 9. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Google Play -> поиск -> Remote Desktop Microsoft. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.rdc.androidx Приложение на телефон, необходимые разрешения на компьютере. https://aka.ms/rdsetup Всё, управляй.

Comment: @Akina, да вот не видит мой комп. Точнее, я нажимаю в списке компьютеров на мой комп и выводит ошибку, что невозможно подключиться.

Comment: Значит, нет необходимых разрешений на компьютере. В файрволе, в групповых политиках и т.п.